# How can I use sshfs to mount a remote drive (BeagleBone) on my Mac?

Tags: macos, ssh, fuse, sshfs

Why can't I connect to my BeagleBone using sshfs from my mac?  I can ssh to this ip address just fine.
Do I need to somehow create a special mount point?  What does it mean that the socket is not connected?

```
sudo sshfs root@192.168.7.1: /Volumes/
remote host has disconnected
mount_osxfusefs: failed to mount /Volumes@/dev/osxfuse0: Socket is not connected
```

FYI I installed sshfs using `brew cask sshfs`

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I've done it in the past. (I'm not sure if it is the same sshfs implementation you used though)

I have a private key (I will call it mykey.pem)
Make sure its permissions are 600

I also have a folder that I will mount on (It will be at /usr/remote)

Then I run this:

```
sshfs -o IdentityFile=/path/to/key/mykey.pem remote_user@ip_address:/remote/folder -o allow_other /usr/remote
```

I hope this is helpful for your situation.

Comment: does there need to be a matching key on the server?